# C# Speech Recognition: Dynamically Reading Input

Tags: c#, speech-recognition

As part of an A.I. program that I'm writing, I would like to know if it is possible to print to the screen what the the default Windows SpeechRecognitionEngine is hearing. It's hard to explain, but I have a text box that's locked in my window, and as the engine is listening to what you're saying, I'd like the textbox to display what it's hearing/what words it's picked up, and I'd like it to do this AS it's hearing you. Afterwards, if it's heard you say a command that it recognizes, it will display the command in the textbox (this part has successfully been incorporated), and if it doesn't know what you said (if it wasn't a command), I'd like it to display what you said in red text.

If anybody knows how to dynamically get the speech recognition engine's 'thoughts' as it's listening, in C# of course, please do let me know how I can use this.

I hope I've explained what it is I'm trying to achieve, and I hope you understand.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You can 'listen' to [SpeechHypothesized](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognitionengine.speechhypothesized.aspx) event, which is meant for debugging and contain several [RecognitionResult](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.recognitionresult.aspx) (the partially recognized word, alternatives, etc)

Comment: Yes, I'm using this, however it only shows words from the command list that it recognizes, as oppose to what words it's hearing, if that makes sense

Comment: I have a command that will show a log of the session (anything the program speaks out loud or any commands the user says). This command is called "show logger". If I say "show logger" into the microphone, it will show the log, and there will be an entry 2nd to last saying "Show Logger". But if I said "Can you show me the logger?", the command will still run, because it recognizes the words "show" and "logger" in the sentence, but it will still only display "Show Logger" in the log, as oppose to the whole sentence that I said. I hope this explains better.

Comment: Did you use the [DictationGrammar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.dictationgrammar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or custom grammar?

Comment: I'm using custom grammar.

Comment: How about adding the DictationGrammar alongside the custom grammar for SpeechHypothesized events, but only use the results from your custom grammar?

Comment: Sorry to be a pain, but could you briefly explain how to do that? I'm not entirely familiar with how the speech recognition engine works, I know just about enough to use it to recognize commands that I feed it

Comment: The speech recognition engine can load several grammars, and each grammars (except the DictationGrammar) can use different [priorities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.grammar.priority%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Use the example from both the DictationGrammar & Priorities to setup a speech recognizer with high priority custom grammar and default DictationGrammar. This way you'll receive recognition events for both grammars, and you can simply ignore the result from dictation for command purpose.

Comment: Thank you @Martheen, I will give it a try. I shan't mark this question as answered until I'm able to achieve my goal, as described in the question (displaying live speech input on the screen). Also apologies for the slow replies, my sleep pattern is completely backwards, so...

Comment: @KurtDearnley Also note that the computer can misunderstand you.   The `SpeechHypothesized` events really do contain the best estimate of what the recognizer is thinking.